# Spring jdbcTemplate unit testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am new to Spring and only somewhat experienced  with JUnit and Mockito

I have the following method which requires a unit test

```
public static String getUserNames(final String userName {
  List<String> results = new LinkedList<String>();
   results =  service.getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT USERNAME FROM USERNAMES WHERE NAME = ?", new RowMapper<String>() {
      @Override
      public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
          return new String(rs.getString("USERNAME");
      }
   }

   return results.get(0);      
   },userName)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might achieve this using JUnit and Mockito?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You need to define test application context where which will be picked up by SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. As I see you are trying to perform an integration test and not unit test. These are two different things.

Comment: what aspects of the method do you want to test?  What tests did you try to write?  Show some work.

Comment: You could have a look at [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/) framework for JDBC unit tests

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to do a pure unit test then for the line

```
service.getJdbcTemplate().query("....");
```

You will need to mock the Service, then the service.getJdbcTemplate() method to return a mock JdbcTemplate object, then mock the query method of mocked JdbcTemplate to return the List you need. Something like this:

```
@Mock
Service service;

@Mock
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


@Test
public void testGetUserNames() {

    List<String> userNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    userNames.add("bob");

    when(service.getJdbcTemplate()).thenReturn(jdbcTemplate);
    when(jdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), anyObject()).thenReturn(userNames);

    String retVal = Class.getUserNames("test");
    assertEquals("bob", retVal);
}
```

The above doesn't require any sort of Spring support. If you were doing an Integration Test where you actually wanted to test that data was being pulled from a DB properly, then you would probably want to use the Spring Test Runner.

Comment: I am getting following exception. I followed same like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374823/spring-jdbctemplate-junit

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Spring Test to do this. Take a look a the documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

You need to create a test using @RunWith and use your spring conf with @ContextConfiguration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring-config.xml")
public class SpringAppTests {
    @Autowired
    private HelloService helloService;

    @Test
    public void testSayHello() {
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello world!", helloService.sayHello());
    }
}
```

Here you have a little explanation from the documentation:

**@Runwith**

> @Runwith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class), developers can implement
>   standard JUnit 4.4 unit and integration tests and simultaneously reap
>   the benefits of the TestContext framework such as support for loading
>   application contexts, dependency injection of test instances,
>   transactional test method execution, etc.

**@ContextConfiguration**

> @ContextConfiguration Defines class-level metadata that is used to
>   determine how to load and configure an ApplicationContext for
>   integration tests. Specifically, @ContextConfiguration declares either
>   the application context resource locations or the annotated classes
>   that will be used to load the context. Hope to help

Hope to help

Comment: Thank You Fede.. I think I need to be more specific about what I want to achieve... I want to know if it is possible to Mock the return of the jdbcTemplate.query method with JUnit and Mockito... Thank you

Comment: @Mat sorry for missunderstand you needed. If you want I can delete the answer. Btw, in that case you need mockito, you can take a look at this page http://gojko.net/2009/10/23/mockito-in-six-easy-examples/