# mocking overloading method queryForObject in JdbcTemplate

Tags: mockito, jdbctemplate

How to mock below code using mockito?

```
@Override
@Nullable
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes, Class<T> requiredType)
        throws DataAccessException {

    return queryForObject(sql, args, argTypes, getSingleColumnRowMapper(requiredType));
}
```

I have tried below:

```
  @Test
    public void testGetCount(){

        Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),Mockito.refEq(Object[].class),
                Mockito.refEq(Integer[].class), Mockito.eq(Long.class)))
                .thenAnswer((Answer<Long>) invocation -> 2l);
        User user = new User(userDetails);
        Assert.assertEquals(2,dao.getCount(user));
    }
```

Please note that I have tried with `Mockito.eq` instead of `Mockito.refEq`, but ended in same result.

but it is always calling the below method:

```
@Override
    public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType, @Nullable Object... args) throws DataAccessException {
        return queryForObject(sql, args, getSingleColumnRowMapper(requiredType));
    }
```

Whole class here:

```
    public class UserDetailsAggregationDaoTest {

        private final String userDetails = "10015-MTBD";

        @InjectMocks
        private UserDao dao = new UserDaoImpl();

        @Mock
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;




   @Test
        public void testGetCount(){
            //Using Mockito.refEq
            Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),Mockito.refEq(Object[].class),
                    Mockito.refEq(Integer[].class), Mockito.eq(Long.class)))
                    .thenAnswer((Answer<Long>) invocation -> 2l);
            User user = new User(userDetails);
            Assert.assertEquals(2,dao.getCount(user));
        }


    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123683/spring-jdbctemplate-unit-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by change it like below:

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),Mockito.any(Object[].class),Mockito.any(int[].class), Mockito.eq(Long.class)))
            .thenReturn(2l);
```